# how to noindex a few images with the robots.txt file

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I'd like to noindex a few images that are on my website, how to disallow the robots from indexing them?

I edited the robots.txt, here's what it looks like:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: Slurp
User-agent: msnbot 
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
User-agent: Yahoo-MMCrawler
Disallow: 

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2016/06/image4.jpg
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2016/06/image3.jpg
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2016/05/image2.jpg
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/2016/06/image1.jpg
```

One of the images that wasn't supposed to be indexed, appears in the Google Image results.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, but I would presume Google already indexed your images before you disallowed them in your robots.txt.

Remove them from Googles index in Search Console:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal

After that, fetch and submit your site again.